# What's a good automated way to change Python 2 code to code that is compatible with Python 2 and 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2to3

I'm changing some Python 2 code to be compatible with Python 2 and Python 3. The translation tool [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) works well at converting Python 2 code to Python 3 code that is not necessarily compatible with Python 2 code. An example is how it converts `x.iteritems()` to `x.items()`. What I might need is automated conversion of `x.iteritems()` to `list(x.items())`, and so on for all Python code.

How can this be done?

Comment: "What I might need is automated conversion of x.iteritems() to list(x.items())" um, but that would not be equivalent... anyway, you might want to check out [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, that's the point. I need the code that is compatible only with Python 2 to be changed automatically to be compatible with *both* Python 2 and Python 3. The tool `2to3` seems to convert the code such that it becomes compatible *only* with Python 3.

Comment: How is `x.items()` not compatible with Python 2?

Comment: @chepner In Python 2 `x.items()` returns a list of (key, value) pairs while in Python 3 `x.items()` is an `itemview` object which has to be iterated over, so `list(x.items())` is required to replace what was `x.items()` in Python 2.

Comment: But you didn't have `x.items()` in your original Python 2; you had `iteritems()`. Your proposed change results in the same semantics when run under 2 and 3, but still changes the semantics from the original. Without using `2to3`, there *is* no single method that will preserve your original semantics under both 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) module, it will give you exactly what you are looking for! Once you complete the transition, you can replace the `six` methods with native python 3.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. It looks like it might be a solution. However, I really need a tool to convert existing Python 2 code to code that, say, features the `six` module. I'm looking for an automated solution.

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't believe there is an equivalent of `2to3` for `six`. In these situations, as arduous as it might sound, I make sure that everything has unit tests, set the tests to run on both python 2 and 3 during CI, and then start inserting `six` where appropriate.